# FileStream vs/differences StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, io, filestream, streamwriter

What is difference between **FileStream** and **StreamWriter** in .NET?

What context are you supposed to use it? What is their advantage and disadvantage?

Is it possible to combine these two into one?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

> What is different between FileStream and StreamWriter in dotnet?

A `FileStream` is a `Stream`. Like all Streams it only deals with `byte[]` data.

A `StreamWriter : TextWriter` is a Stream-decorator. A TextWriter  encodes the primitive types like string, int and char to `byte[]` and then writes that to the linked Stream.

> What context are you supposed to use it? What is their advantage and disadvantage?

You use a bare FileStream when you have `byte[]` data. You add a `StreamWriter` when you want to write text. Use a Formatter or a Serializer to write more complex data.

> Is it possible to combine these two into one?

Yes. You always need a Stream to create a StreamWriter. The helper method `System.IO.File.CreateText("path")` will create them in combination and then you only have to Dispose() the outer writer.

Comment: Also is important to note that `FileStream` is a type of stream, that is specifically tailored towards files.  Streams natively work with bytes, however `StreamWriter` / Reader will write / read text on *any* stream, not just `FileStream`s.  For example, `MemoryStreams`, `NetworkStreams`, etc..

Answer (score 22):

FileStream writes bytes, StreamWriter writes text.  That's all.

Comment: Actually, that's not "all"...  But it is one correct difference.

Answer (score 16):

A FileStream is explicitly intended for working files.

A StreamWriter can be used to stream to any type of [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) -  network sockets, files, etc.

ScottGu explains the different Stream objects quite nicely here: http://www.codeguru.com/Csharp/Csharp/cs_data/streaming/article.php/c4223

Comment: Excellent reference for streams, although it does not cover random access R/W streams. Especially the serialization/deserialization information and the demonstration of non-file streams are very useful. +1

Comment: Reference is no longer available.

Answer (score 9):

They are two different levels used in outputting information to known data sources.

A `FileStream` is a type of Stream, which is conceptually a mechanism that points to some location and can handle incoming and/or outgoing data to and from that location. Streams exist for reading/writing to files, network connections, memory, pipes, the console, debug and trace listeners, and a few other types of data sources. Specifically, a `FileStream` exists to perform reads and writes to the file system. Most streams are pretty low-level in their usage, and deal with data as bytes.

A `StreamWriter` is a wrapper for a Stream that simplifies using that stream to output plain text. It exposes methods that take strings instead of bytes, and performs the necessary conversions to and from byte arrays. There are other Writers; the other main one you'd use is the `XmlTextWriter`, which facilitates writing data in **XML** format. There are also Reader counterparts to the Writers that similarly wrap a Stream and facilitate getting the data back out.

Answer (score 8):

Well, from the MSDN for [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx):

> Exposes a Stream around a file, supporting both synchronous and asynchronous read and write operations.

and the MSDN for [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx):

> Implements a TextWriter for writing characters to a stream in a particular encoding.

The most obvious difference is that `FileStream` allows read/write operations, while `StreamWriter` is write only.

The `StreamWriter` page goes on to add:

> StreamWriter is designed for character output in a particular encoding, whereas classes derived from Stream are designed for byte input and output.

So a second difference is that `FileStream` is for bytes, while `StreamWriter` is for text.

Answer (score 5):

One key difference (in addition to the above comments), could be that `FileStream` supports random disk access read and writes to any specified `FileStream.Position`. For large file modifications, that can be invaluable.