# Which writing to file method to use?

Tags: c#

I'm really getting confused by how many different ways there is to write data to a file just with **System.IO**.
I mean, between `FileStream`, `StreamWriter` or just the **System.IO.file** methods... Which one is the best to use?

It even gets more confusing when you see you can use different constructs with any of them, like using `using` or not.

Is there any difference between them? Online tutorials seems to only stick to one of them and completely ignores the other ones. Some of these tutorials are even using different ways of referencing the file to write in (using the `File` type in some cases, `FileInfo` types in others, or even just a string for its path/name).

Any of them is more efficient than the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Stream` is an abstraction for "bytes of data" that works with things other than files, like bytes sent over a network.

`TextReader`s and `TextWriter`s are meant for working with **text**. `StreamReader`s and `StreamWriter`s are specific kinds which wrap `Stream`s.

The `File` class is specifically meant to treat a file as a **unit** entity, not as long stream of bytes. Hence:

- If the file **could** be *big* (I'd say that means 1 MiB+), use the `Stream`-related classes. It usually makes no sense to keep a 10-MiB `byte[]` or `string` in memory, *unless you really need **random access** to **all** of it*.
- If it's always small (so that it makes sense to keep it all in memory), you can just use the `File` class to read and write `byte[]`s or `string`s.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many ways because there are many ways to structure data to send. Do you have arrays of strings? Are you streaming data from some other source (like a network stream)? Do you want to write lines of text like a log?

It would help to know what you want to write, then we can help you decide how.

Oh, and always use 'using' if you can. You get resource cleanup even if your code fails which is a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

The `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` classes are designed for reading and writing **text**, and the `FileStream` class is designed for **binary** (non-text) data.

Answer (score 1):

There are some other interesting points about this on the following question:

[FileStream vs/differences StreamWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963667/filestream-vs-differences-streamwriter)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which level of abstraction you need to work with and what kind of data you're working with (text vs. binary).

If you just need to dump data into a file, you can use the helper methods on the `File` class—`WriteAllBytes()` for binary (it just writes to a `FileStream` for you) and the `WriteAllLines()` or `WriteAllText()` for text (they use a `StreamWriter` for this, using an `UTF8NoBOM` encoding unless otherwise specified).

A `StreamWriter` lets you write text to a specified stream, which may be a `FileStream` or some other kind of stream.

If you need to write bytes and you want low-level control, such as specifying file mode, system rights, file-sharing, and other such options, you need to work with a file stream. You may also specify these options to work with text, by passing it to a `StreamWriter` or treating the text as bytes (e.g., by using an `Encoding` object).