# FileStream vs StreamReader and StreamWriter - what's the difference?

Tags: c#, file, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

What functionality is allowed via `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` when working with files which can't be done via `FileStream`, or vice versa? I checked the docs and they both have read / write options, including more advanced ones. So when should I use each of those?

Comment: `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` can use `FileStream` internally, depending on how you construct them. The difference is that the specialised classes are for dealing with only text files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileStream vs/differences StreamWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963667/filestream-vs-differences-streamwriter)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`FileStream` is the lowest-level `Stream` object for working with local files. It therefore works with files as binary (bytes). You can read so many bytes, or write so many bytes.

When it comes to working with text, we have to factor in text encoding. There are many text encodings created for different cultures with different character sets. A common one these days is UTF8 (a form of unicode). Text encoding is the way we tell the computer to represent text as bytes. Using UTF8, the letter "A" would be represented by a single byte, but the Japanese hiragana "あ" would be 3 bytes. Encoding allows us to read and write text correctly. You can read more about that [here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) (in case the link ever breaks: [WaybackMachine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210312143610/https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)).

`StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` are built around reading text, so they handle the encoding for us. One is for reading, and the other is for writing. If you instantiate `StreamReader` or `StreamWriter` using the constructor that accepts a filename, it will actually use `FileStream` internally.

[`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-5.0) gives us methods such as:

- [`ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=net-5.0) - Which reads from the file until carriage return + newline (`\r\n`) or just newline (`\n`) is found, indicating the end of a single line of text, and returns a `string`.
- [`ReadToEnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=net-5.0) - Which reads the entire file contents into a `string`.

[`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-5.0) gives us methods such as:

- [`Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.write?view=net-5.0) - Which can write as little as a single character, or an entire string to the file, but without terminating the line.
- [`WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.writeline?view=net-5.0) which will do the same as `Write`, but it will also end the line so any subsequent writes go to the next line in the file.

In contrast, [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=net-5.0) only has methods like [`Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=net-5.0) and [`Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.write?view=net-5.0), which work with bytes.

Answer (score 6):

A `FileStream` is a Stream. Like all Streams it only deals with byte[] data.

A `StreamWriter` : TextWriter, is a Stream-decorator. A TextWriter encodes Text data like string or char to byte[] and then writes it to the linked Stream.

You use a bare `FileStream` when you have byte[] data. You add a `StreamWriter` when you want to write text. Use a Formatter or a Serializer to write more complex data.

By : [Henk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963667/filestream-vs-differences-streamwriter)